# Jenkins: Invoking REST API (or wget) at end of Jenkins job without writing any script

Tags: jenkins

I thought this should be simple, but I am not able to find any Jenkins plugin which would simply let me call a REST GET API (equivalent of `wget URL`) when the job is finished. Am I missing something here? As I certainly don't want to write a new plugin for this simple task.

I have scanned through all the plugins and the only interesting one are:

- *[Post build task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task)*
- *[Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin)*

But in my case, I don't have access to Jenkins' file system, so I can't write a post-build script to do this job, or neither can I install Groovy on that machine.

Also, Jenkins is running on a Windows Server 2008 machine.

Comment: Actually the post build plugin will allow you to type in the content of the script you'd like to run so you don't have to create a script on the file system

Comment: @Grove - But that would mean I need to have wget equivalent command, which I don't on this windows, and I don't have access to physical machine to do this :).

Comment: You can supply wget.exe along with other files in the SCM checkout (I do that for a few jobs), you don't need to have it already existing in the system. However for a more plugin-oriented approach, see my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a plugin that allows to make an [**HTTP request**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin) (GET and POST) as a **build step**.

There is also a plugin that allows [**any build step**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Any+Build+Step+Plugin) to be used in **post-build actions**.

Use both and you get what you are asking for.

To be able to use any build step as a post-build action, you need to enable this in the settings. Go to:
Jenkins → *Manage Jenkins* → *Configure System* → *Flexible Push* 
and switch the dropdown menu to *"Any build step"*.

Comment: Just a heads up: The referenced HTTP Request plugin is only capable of writing values that are configured as Job Parameters to the HTTP POST's Request Body.

Comment: @Slav -Does the above plugins allows to send xhr request also ?